# Dynamic return type for a class implementing an abstract class in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an abstract class 'AbstractDetailsService' like below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class DetailEntities<T> {
 id: number;
 role:  string;
 data: T[];
}

export class User {
 name: string;
 age: number;
}

export class Customer {
 customerName: string;
 customerAge: number;
}

@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractDetailsService<T> {
 abstract get(entity: string): DetailEntities<T>;
}
```

Then I have a 'PersonDetailsService' class which implements the above class and returns either User or Customer based on what is being passed as entity

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractDetailsService, Customer, DetailEntities, User } from './abstract-detail.service';

@Injectable()
export class PersonDetailsService implements AbstractDetailsService<DetailEntities<any>> {

get(entity: string): DetailEntities<any> {
   if (entity === 'user') {
     const users: User[] = [{name: 'abc', age: 21}]
     const userDetails: DetailEntities<User> = {id: 1, role: 'Developer', data: users};
     return userDetails;
   }
   const customers: Customer[] = [{customerName: 'abc', customerAge: 21}]
   const customerDetails: DetailEntities<Customer> = {id: 1, role: 'Developer', data: customers};
   return customerDetails;
 }
}
```

This is my component code where I am injecting PersonDetailsService in the providers array:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import {
 AbstractDetailsService,
 DetailEntities,
User
} from "./abstract-detail.service";
import { PersonDetailsService } from "./person-detail.service";

@Component({
 selector: "my-app",
 templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
 providers: [
   {
     provide: AbstractDetailsService,
     useClass: PersonDetailsService
   }
 ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
 details: DetailEntities<User>;

 constructor(private readonly detailService: AbstractDetailsService<any>) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
   const entity = "user";
   this.details = this.detailService.get(entity);
 }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can replace the types as `any` to either `User` or `Customer`. How can I have the 'get' function whose return type is dynamic? Also the generic type should only accept User and Customer.

Stackblitz url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typescript-dynamic-return-type?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-detail.service.ts

I would appreciate your help on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple solution could be the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).

Instead of

```js
get(entity: string): DetailEntities<any>
```

you could declare

```js
get(entity: string): DetailEntities<User | Customer>
```

A more complex solution could use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).